# How to retrieve elements from a multidimensional ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following as part of a multidimensional arrayList called AcidExp

```
[[[Acid Exposure (pH),  Total], [,  Total Normal], [Clearance pH  :  Channel 7], [Number of Acid Episodes,  22], [Time,  20.6 min], [Percent Time,  2.7%], [Mean Acid Clearance Time,  56 sec], [Longest Episode,  2.7 min], [Gastric pH  :  Channel 8], [Time pH<4.0,  713.8 min], [Percent Time,  93.3%]]]

[[[Reflux Study Summary], [Acid Exposure (pH),  Upright, Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal], [# of Episodes Channel 7,  24, 0, 24], [Percent Time Clearance pH,  3.2%,  (< 6.3),  0.0%,  (< 1.2),  1.8%,  (< 4.2)]]]

[[[blabla], [jonny,  billy, judy, tim], [pH,  3.2%,  0.0%,  1.8%]]]
```

I can't seem to be able to refer to each of the ArrayLists individually so I can manipulate them individually.

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> AcidExp = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
     Pattern tu1 = Pattern.compile("Acid Exposure \\(pH\\)");
     Pattern tu2 = Pattern.compile("Upright");
     for (List<String> row : twoDim) {
         boolean found = false;

             if (tu1.matcher(row.get(0).toString()).matches()) {
                 found = true;
              break;
             }
         if (found) {
             AcidExp.add((ArrayList<List<String>>) twoDim);
             System.out.println(AcidExp.get(0));
         }
     }
```

but this just gives me the original with the outer bracket removed.

```
[[Acid Exposure (pH),  Total], [,  Total Normal], [Clearance pH  :  Channel 7], [Number of Acid Episodes,  22], [Time,  20.6 min], [Percent Time,  2.7%], [Mean Acid Clearance Time,  56 sec], [Longest Episode,  2.7 min], [Gastric pH  :  Channel 8], [Time pH<4.0,  713.8 min], [Percent Time,  93.3%]]

    [[Reflux Study Summary], [Acid Exposure (pH),  Upright, Recumbent, Total], [,  Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total], [Normal], [# of Episodes Channel 7,  24, 0, 24], [Percent Time Clearance pH,  3.2%,  (< 6.3),  0.0%,  (< 1.2),  1.8%,  (< 4.2)]]

    [[blabla], [jonny,  billy, judy, tim], [pH,  3.2%,  0.0%,  1.8%]]
```

How can I then refer to each List within the ArrayList individually?

Currently if I do

```
`AcidExp.get(0).get(1)` I just get 

[Acid Exposure (pH),  Total]
[Reflux Study Summary]
[blabla]
```

And If I do

```
AcidExp.get(1)
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

I think it's something to do with the fact that all the ArrayLists I want are stored in the first element of AcidExp I suppose but I think I'm getting all my ArrayLists mixed up

Comment: Can you maybe explain exactly what value you would like to see end up in AcidExp? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to get an array of the matching arrays

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what the problem is, but in the body of your `if`-clause you added a `break`-statement, so the loop ends there. The `if(found)`-part is within the loop, so it will never be executed - you're leaving the loop as soon as `found` is set to `true`. Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think Ive figured out what you are trying to achieve. You're basically trying to find the set that has "Acid Exposure (ph)" as one of its elements. The error is basically that you only have one loop iterating through the dataset, where you need two.

You can then loop through all the sets, and then loop through all elements in each set. Then, as soon as the match is made, you can break out of the inner loop but still continue looking through the remaining sets.

See below code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<List<String>> set1 = new ArrayList() {{
        add(Arrays.asList("Acid Exposure (pH)", "Total"));
        add(Arrays.asList("", "Total Normal"));
        add(Arrays.asList("AClearance pH  :  Channel 7"));
        add(Arrays.asList("Number of Acid Episodes",  "22"));
    }};

    List<List<String>> set2 = new  ArrayList() {{
        add(Arrays.asList("Reflux Study Summary"));
        add(Arrays.asList("Acid Exposure (pH)", "Upright", "Recumbent", "Total"));
    }};

    List<List<String>> set3 = new  ArrayList() {{
        add(Arrays.asList("blabla"));
        add(Arrays.asList("jonny", "billy", "judy", "tim"));
    }};

    List<List<List<String>>> twoDim = new ArrayList() {{
        add(set1);
        add(set2);
        add(set3);
    }};

    ArrayList<List<List<String>>> acidExp = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern tu1 = Pattern.compile("Acid Exposure \\(pH\\)");
    for (List<List<String>> row : twoDim) {
        for(List<String> element : row) {
            String val = element.get(0);
            if (tu1.matcher(val).matches()) {
                acidExp.add(row);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(acidExp);
}
```

Output:

```
[[[Acid Exposure (pH), Total], [, Total Normal], [AClearance pH  :  Channel 7], [Number of Acid Episodes, 22]], [[Reflux Study Summary], [Acid Exposure (pH), Upright, Recumbent, Total]]]
```

The acidExp variable will now only contain the first set (Note you do not actually need the boolean flag).

Comment: OK. Isee what you're doing here. The problem is that twoDim is declared as List<List<String>> which means that row has to be declared as List<String> so that I can't use the add method on acidExp